# Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am using `recaptcha` v2

I am getting the following error occasionally (sometimes i don't get error and sometimes i do get it)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined
```

It seems because of the internal http request. that takes some time to get another js `recaptcha__en.js`. Meanwhile actual rendering code of `grecaptcha` executes.

So what is the standard solution to avoid this issue.?

PS : of course i am looking for some solution other than `setTimeout`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Recaptcha has a `onload` callback that will run once recaptcha is loaded. Place your code inside that callback function.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

```
<script>
    function onloadCallback() {
        /* Place your recaptcha rendering code here */
    }
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"></script>
```

Comment: but i want to render the captcha challenge not on pageload. i want to render it after user enters into some bootstrap modal

Comment: @nodeofcode It is not page `onload`. This is provided by recaptcha. I have updated my answer with the example

Comment: i do get your point.. but how can i render captcha into block which doesn't exists

Comment: I didn't get what you meant by **but how can i render captcha into block which doesn't exists** ?

Comment: grecaptcha.render(<somedivid>, paramObj) .. here somedivid need to exists in DOM in order that captcha renders into this div. Now If i provide onload query param, then the callback executes right after the scripts get loaded, and at that time i don't have that somedivid.

Comment: I can get your point but i am not sure when `<somedivid>` will be available in DOM ? What you can do is, once you rendered `<somedivid>`, then you can inject captcha script with `onload` callback.

Comment: If you want to load grecaptcha on page load, then set a boolean inside the callback of `onload` and check against the boolean before rendering recaptcha.

Comment: Of course the wrapper www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js, get loaded. then my code get executed. But In this case, i have to inject recaptcha__en.js, not api.js. So the question in how do i inject second level code that is recaptcha__en.js?

Comment: @nodeofcode Why do you need to do that ? Any how `api.js` will do some pre-processing and will inject `recaptcha__en.js` (language specific code).

Comment: I had already injected api.js before this question was asked. Then i found that api.js does load recaptcha__en.js but only after its injection get resolved.

Comment: You can inject `recaptcha__en.js` yourself but i don't recommend it. Moreover, i think the content of `recaptcha__en.js` is dynamic. So, it is better to use `api.js` as suggested by them.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved this by ordering the script in below manner

#### HTML

```
<div id="review_recaptcha"></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var review_recaptcha_widget;
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        if($('#review_recaptcha').length) {
            review_recaptcha_widget = grecaptcha.render('review_recaptcha', {
              'sitekey' : '<?php echo $site_key?>'
            });
        }
      };      
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

It works on landing page and also in bootstrap 4 popup form:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=ADD-YOUR-RECAPTCHA-SITE-KEY-HERE"></script>
<script>
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  if(window.grecaptcha){
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('ADD-YOUR-RECAPTCHA-SITE-KEY-HERE', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
              $('#i-recaptcha').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="' + token + '">');
            });
        });
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 100);
</script>
```

Thanks for asking this question. :)

Answer (score 3):

My Problem got resolved by doing following changes in the script code (:

i.e from internal path

`<script src='static/js/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`

to external google path i.e

`<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`

Answer (score 2):

For me it was working for years then suddenly stopped.

switching the API load from

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

to having async and defer fixed it

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the application loads several times the script `'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js` after refresh, make sure your application doesn't have multiple `<script async="" defer="" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a callback, another async solution is explained in the [recaptcha docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/loading):

> When loading reCAPTCHA asynchronously, keep in mind that reCAPTCHA
> cannot be used until it has finished loading. For example, the
> following code would likely break:

```
<script async src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script>
  // If reCAPTCHA is still loading, grecaptcha will be undefined.
  grecaptcha.ready(function(){
    grecaptcha.render("container", {
      sitekey: "ABC-123"
    });
  });
</script>
```

> In some situations, adjusting script ordering can be enough to prevent
> race conditions. Alternatively, you can prevent race conditions by
> including the following code snippet on pages that load reCAPTCHA. If
> you are using grecaptcha.ready() to wrap API calls, add the following
> code snippet to ensure that reCAPTCHA can be called at any time.

```
<script async src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script>
  // How this code snippet works:
  // This logic overwrites the default behavior of `grecaptcha.ready()` to
  // ensure that it can be safely called at any time. When `grecaptcha.ready()`
  // is called before reCAPTCHA is loaded, the callback function that is passed
  // by `grecaptcha.ready()` is enqueued for execution after reCAPTCHA is
  // loaded.
  if(typeof grecaptcha === 'undefined') {
    grecaptcha = {};
  }
  grecaptcha.ready = function(cb){
    if(typeof grecaptcha === 'undefined') {
      // window.__grecaptcha_cfg is a global variable that stores reCAPTCHA's
      // configuration. By default, any functions listed in its 'fns' property
      // are automatically executed when reCAPTCHA loads.
      const c = '___grecaptcha_cfg';
      window[c] = window[c] || {};
      (window[c]['fns'] = window[c]['fns']||[]).push(cb);
    } else {
      cb();
    }
  }

  // Usage
  grecaptcha.ready(function(){
    grecaptcha.render("container", {
      sitekey: "ABC-123"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure why but I couldn't get this working for v3. https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=loadReCaptcha&render={key} seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but maybe this will help someone.  The reason I was getting this 'Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined' error was because I couldn't reach the dependency js file (recaptcha_en.js) which is hosted on [www.gstatic.com](http://www.gstatic.com).  Once I solved that issue, it worked for me.

Comment: link isn't valid

Comment: It wasn't meant as a link, it was meant as a hostname.  This server was blocked by my network policy which is what caused the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by updating site key and secret key. Actually I was using v3 API but used v2 configuration.

After using v3 key, my captcha is working fine.