# Wordpress recapche showing 400 bad Request

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, contact-form-7

I have integrated google reCapche
But it is not showing in my contact form 7
Showing an error
Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822607/uncaught-referenceerror-grecaptcha-is-not-defined)

Comment: please share plugin name and version

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the best solution (before the 5.1 version of the plugin was released on December 18).  It allows you to keep Contact Form 7, but also use the V2 methodology.  Here are the steps for implementation:

- Add and activate this plugin
  https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-nocaptcha-recaptcha/
- Go to the settings of the new plugin and insert the Google ReCaptcha V2 keys (you can also edit other settings there)
- Remove any v3 Google keys from Contact Form 7 > Integration and remove the Contact Form 7 shortcode [recaptcha]
- Add the shortcode [anr_nocaptcha g-recaptcha-response] that is supported by the new plugin and save the form.
- If still has an issue with this fix, please contact the plugin developer.

**There is also an alternate similar solution here:**

https://articles.runtings.co.uk/2018/12/how-to-fix-contact-form-7-v501.html

**Case 2 : Permission issue on server**

- To use CAPTCHA, you need GD and FreeType library installed on your server.
- Also, make sure that CAPTCHA’s temporary folder is writable. For details, 
  https://contactform7.com/captcha/